# Limitations of rational numbers

Tags: irrational-numbers

I have been looking at the popular proofs that rational numbers have limitations when trying to define real-world lengths.

For instance, there does not exist a rational $c$ such that $c^2=2$.
Basically, proofs focus upon the fact that all square roots of natural numbers, other than of perfect squares, are irrational.

I would like to see other illustrations of proofs that show existence of irrational numbers without relying upon square roots of natural numbers.   But on other areas of mathematics.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The issue is with how vague this is. The most natural "next step" of generalization would be all numbers of the form $\sqrt[a]{b}$, but even this doesn't cover everything: realistically, it only broaches into what we call "algebraic numbers" (those which can be the roots of a polynomial). Even beyond that (or rather, the opposite of that) you have the transcendentals, like $e$ or $\pi$ which, to my knowledge, aren't so easy to "generate" outside of the natural contexts in which they arise. (In part, this is because there is a rigorous sense in which "almost all" numbers are transcendental.)

Comment: @PrincessEev *roots of a polynomial with integer coefficients (not all vanishing). Just being nitpicky :)

Comment: A valid and important nitpick nonetheless, that is my bad.

Comment: The [proof that $e$ is irrational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational) is elementary and pretty easy to follow for a first-year calculus student.

Comment: Would you be so kind to show me the one using roots of a polynomial with integer coefficients ?

Answer (score 1):

A rational number's decimal representation is terminating or eventually periodic.  So, for example, consider $0.1101001000100001\ldots$, where the numbers of $0$'s between successive $1$'s  are $0,1,2,3,4,\ldots$.  This is neither terminating nor eventually periodic, so this number is irrational.

[EDIT] BTW, this particular example happens to be $$\frac{10^{\frac{1}{8}} \vartheta_{2}\! \left(0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\right)}{20}$$
where $\vartheta_2$ is a Jacobi theta function.

Comment: Can one show that rational number decimal representation is terminating or eventually periodic ?  Where can I find it ?

Comment: One way to do it is via the pigeonhole principle - when you divide $p$ by $q$, there are $q$ possible remainders you can get. Therefore, when you calculate the decimal representation of $\frac{p}{q}$, once you reach the point where you're always appending a zero when you do the division, go another $q+1$ steps. Somewhere in those $q+1$ steps there must be two divisions using the same remainder, and so everything after that will form a loop and hence a repeating decimal expansion.

Comment: Where can I find this? Would like to scrutinise it in more detail.

Comment: See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal)